# How to Update LisBox ItemSource On Button Click

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a ListBox;

```
  <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 x:Name="customerListBox"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Customername"
                 SelectionMode="Single" Width="200"/>
```

Customers is  `public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }`

Now I am binding ListBox Selected Item to a Text Box:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=customerListBox,
Path=SelectedValue.Customername,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

I have made it one-way as there I want to commit the changes only on click of my Save button and not when the value change on TextBlock.

```
<Button Content="Save" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Width="80" Height="30"
                           Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
```

Comment: show save command code here ? ... as its one way binding how do you map it to your source ?

Comment: @Muds I want to Update the ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" on SaveCommand, nothing doing there now

Comment: Unless you Push your changes to your object you can not get them in your object because there is not binding support... till then its just textbox.text

Comment: Could you Show in the code please

Comment: are you using mvvm or code behind ? or both may b ;)

Comment: @Simsons what is the problem? what error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going the wrong way about it, imho.

Don't bind `TextBox` directly against selected item. Rather, create a new command, `SelectionChangedCommand`, and new property, `CurrentlyActiveText`, bind it against `TextBox`.

The logic would be simple:

```
SelectionChangedCommand = new RelayCommand(selectedItem=> {
   // todo: ask user if he wants to commit the previous changes?!
   CurrentlyActiveText = (string)selectedItem;
 })

 SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(() => {
   yourObservable[SelectedIndex] = CurrentlyActiveText;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a nicer way of doing this is using Triggers to fire a Command on the ListBox SelectionChanged event. Putting logic in a property setter always feels a bit *wrong* to me

```
<ListBox...>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
           <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CustomerListBoxSelectionChanged}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=customerListBox,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListBox>
```

In your view model:

```
public Customer CurrentCustomer { get; set; }

public RelayCommand<Customer> CustomerListBoxSelectionChanged { get; set; }

private void OnCustomerListBoxSelectionChanged(Customer customer)
{
    CurrentCustomer = customer;
    NewCustomerName = customer.CustomerName;
}

private string _newCustomerName;

public string NewCustomerName
{
    get { return _newCustomerName; }
    set
    {
        if (_newCustomerName == value)
            return;

         _newCustomerName = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("NewCustomerName");
    }
}
```

Your TextBox in your XAML becomes:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewCustomerName}"/>
```

And finally, your SaveCommand calls a method that simply does...

```
private void OnSave()
{
    CurrentCustomer.CustomerName = NewCustomerName;
}
```

Note you will also need to make sure that your CustomerName in your Customer object is raising PropertyChanged events in order to reflect the update in your ListBox

Note that doing it this way also saves you a futher lookup the ObservableCollection to perform an update. It'll save you some time - any performance gain is always good :)